# Large memory pages and fragmentation

Tags: linux, memory-management, shared-memory, powerpc

I am using Linux + PPC64 where the memory page size is 64KiB. If I were to make two separate 32KiB allocations from within the same process, would that take up a single page in memory or two? Thanks!

Comment: How are you allocating the memory?

Comment: It is somewhat of a hypothetical question, but I am thinking something like shmget. If heap allocations are treated differently, I'd appreciate it if that is pointed out as well. Thanks!

Comment: Well, in the case of something like `malloc()`, it might store bookkeeping data adjacent to the allocation. So a 64K allocation actually uses `64K+sizeof(header)` bytes.

Comment: Two `shmget()` calls probably can't use the same memory page at all, since  the granularity of virtual memory mapping is the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kernel will assign 64KiB for each request less than 64 KiB.